# Expressing $\mathrm{B}(\sinh(x), \cosh(x))$ in terms of elementary functions

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions

Is it possible to express:

$\mathrm{B}(\sinh(x), \cosh(x))$

(where $\mathrm{B}$ is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function))

In closed form, in terms of elementary functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my "NO" (sort-of) answer.  Compute the series
$$
\mathrm{B}(\sinh x, \cosh x) = \frac{1}{x}-{\frac {1}{6}}x-\frac{1}{12}\,{\pi }^{2}{x}^{2}+ \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\zeta 
 \left( 3 \right) +{\frac {7}{360}} \right) {x}^{3}+O \left( {x}^{4}
 \right) 
$$
But $\zeta(3)$ is not known to occur in any elementary function.  SO: if this is elementary, it will provide a new expression for $\zeta(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of closed form, $B(sinh(x),cosh(x))$ is already a closed form. So, the question is "What do you expect ? ". Another closed form is $\Gamma(sinh(x))\Gamma(cosh(x))/\Gamma(cosh(x)+sinh(x))$. I cannot say if it is a better closed form or not. In terms of a finite number of only elementary functions, I think that it is impossible (if an integral is excluded as a kind of closed form).

Comment: In looking at this problem I noted that while $\Gamma(\cosh(x) + \sinh(x)) = \Gamma(e^x) = e^{-x}e^{x!}$ and $\Gamma(\sinh(x)) = {\rm csch}(x)\sinh(x)!$, I could not seem to find an equivalent expression for $\Gamma(\cosh(x))$.  Frustrating!

Comment: Traditionally, B and $\Gamma$ are not called "elementary".  So certainly $\Gamma(\sinh x)$ is not elementary.  But the OP asks if the particular combination $\mathrm{B}(\sinh x, \cosh x)$ is.

Comment: $x!$ in not an elementary function if $x$ is not an integer.